# Socket IO using functions in event listener

Tags: angular, typescript, web, socket.io

I'm using socket io in Angular 2 and I have a problem with:

```
this.socket.on('response_navbar', function (data) {
  console.log(data.entryTypeCollection);
  this.test123();
});

test123() {
   console.log('Test');
}
```

after event `'response_navbar'` will come, console.log() is working, but when I try to call function `this.test123();` I recieve error

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using `this`, you should use arrow function to keep the context.

```
this.socket.on('response_navbar', (data) => {
  console.log(data.entryTypeCollection);
  this.test123();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you answer, why function(){} and () => {} make sence???

Comment: @BakhtierGaibulloev this is new feature of ES6, without arrow function, we can also bind `this` manually.

Comment: The `this` keyword is automatically bound by the anonymous `function () {}` to `this.socket`. By using an arrow function `() => {}` or manually binding `function () {}.bind(this)`, the function inherits the surrounding context which is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I have this code to initialize my NodeJs server with SocketIO

```
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ....
    }
```

It is not required that you put This, because `this.test123` makes reference to the context within `socket.on`